# How to return HTML code from Lambda function in NodeJS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda-edge

I have the following Lambda function. I need to return some custom html when the function is called.

I tried:

```
    exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {   
        const response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/html',
            },
            body: String("Hi there !"),
        };
        return response;
    }
```

But when invoking the function, I'm getting the following error : The Lambda function returned an invalid entry in the headers object: Each header entry in the headers object must be an array. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time.

I took the code from AWS blueprint :

[image]

Original code from AWS :

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Using your code I deployed one https://v7jcebje7mvvl6qfjnddimlk5q0tfrez.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/  (I will remove this soon), and all seems to work fine. I dont see any error log in the log group either

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Woohaik. Does yours work behind a cloudfront distribution? In a client request for example?

Comment: Is this regular AWS Lambda or Lambda@Edge?

Comment: @jarmod it's Lambda@Edge

Comment: As error message saying can you please try like this if it works : `headers: {
    'Content-Type': ['text/html'],
  }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You appear to have used the regular AWS Lambda blueprint. Edge Lambda functions are different e.g. the status code is returned in `status`, not in `statusCode`.

Based on the documented [example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-examples.html):

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const response = {
        status: '200',
        statusDescription: 'OK',
        headers: {
            'cache-control': [{
                key: 'Cache-Control',
                value: 'max-age=100'
            }],
            'content-type': [{
                key: 'Content-Type',
                value: 'text/html'
            }]
        },
        body: "some HTML content here",
    };
    callback(null, response);
};
```